# How to change the view/location in Google api StreetViewPanorama

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to change the location of panorama but it shows different location and some times it doesn't show anything.

[Location 1](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Loyola+School/@40.7784525,-73.9589767,3a,90y,31.35h,96.74t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sAF1QipMFjDabjIiv8AgkMaSMFFZixaBiLARqUl3aQ-_2!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipMFjDabjIiv8AgkMaSMFFZixaBiLARqUl3aQ-_2%3Dw129-h106-k-no-pi-0-ya2.1627703-ro-0-fo100!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x9e176350cde2068f!8m2!3d40.7784737!4d-73.9588973)

[Location 2](https://www.google.ca/maps/place/Loyola+School/@40.778483,-73.9589043,3a,75y,346.96h,77.65t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sAF1QipPd-l5QzKcGCTya5oHQXuGhamem2v2QfV9N9J16!2e10!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x9e176350cde2068f!8m2!3d40.7784737!4d-73.9588973)

Can I recreate the panorama view without loading the page?

Thanks

```js
var panorama;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".locationLink").click(function () {
            var index = $(this).attr('index');
            var by = $(this).attr('by');
            changeLocation(index, by);
        });
    });

    var locationsList = [{
        lat: 40.7784525,
        lng: -73.9589767,
        heading: 31.35,
        pitch: 0,
        zoom: 0,
        panoId: 'F:AF1QipMFjDabjIiv8AgkMaSMFFZixaBiLARqUl3aQ-_2'
    },
    {
        lat: 40.778483,
        lng: -73.9589043,
        heading: 346.96,
        pitch: 0,
        zoom: 0,
        panoId: 'F:AF1QipPd-l5QzKcGCTya5oHQXuGhamem2v2QfV9N9J16'
    }];

    function changeLocation(index, by) {

        var location = locationsList[index];

        var fenway = { lat: location.lat, lng: location.lng };

        if (by === 'pano')
            panorama.setPano(location.panoId);
        if (by === 'latlng')
            panorama.setPosition(fenway);
    }

    function initStreetViewPanorama(params) {

        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), {

            pano: params.panoId,
            zoom: params.zoom,
            pov: { heading: params.heading, pitch: params.pitch },
            addressControlOptions: {
                position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
            }

        });
    }
    
    initStreetViewPanorama(locationsList[0]);
```

```css
html,body { height:100%;}
#pano { width:100%; height:99%; }
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="locationLink" index="0" by="pano">Location 1</a> |
    <a href="javascript:;" class="locationLink" index="1" by="pano">Location 2</a>
    <span><b> Change by Lat/Long </b></span>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="locationLink" index="0" by="latlng">Location 1</a> |
    <a href="javascript:;" class="locationLink" index="1" by="latlng">Location 2</a>
</div>
<br>
<div id="pano">
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?">
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I checked your code and it looks like a bug, because if I swap the panoramas in your array the first one works fine, but the second one always gets black screen. It looks like the `setPano()` method is not working smoothly. Also I tried with `setOptions()` method, but got the same black screen. Feel free to file the bug in Google [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=788207)

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73439006